# Minimum number of steps for a Universal Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

Given a Turing Machine M with n states, alphabet A, m variables, a set S indicating the possible values that each variable can take, and an input x, is there a minimum number of steps that M has to take? I'm wondering if it is possible to construct a Turing Machine that takes only one step regardless of any of the aforementioned properties. Or is the number of steps it has to take dependent on one of these properties?

Thank you

Comment: What is a "variable" in the context of Turing machines? What do you mean by a Turing machine taking only one step -- is that for some input, or for all inputs? Turing machines can, in general, loop forever, so there's usually no maximum number of steps.

Comment: By "variable" I was talking about variables in psuedocode that was then converted into a Turing Machine, but I guess that might not be that important. And I'm wondering about what the minimum number of steps a Turing Machine with n states and alphabet A can take for all inputs. That is, if a Turing Machine with 5 states and an alphabet {0, 1} must take at least 5 steps for only one possible input x, then the minimum number of steps it must take is 5. Basically, is there any correlation between the length of a Turing Machine's description and the minimum number of steps it might take?

Comment: "Basically, is there any correlation between the length of a Turing Machine's description and the minimum number of steps it might take?" No: consider the class of Turing machines that implement "If the first character of the input is $0$, halt; otherwise, do some arbitrarily complicated thing with the rest of the input."

Comment: So does this imply that a TM with a description of length m >> 1,000,000 can be simulated on a UTM in just one step, according to this from Wikipedia? -  "F. C. Hennie and R. E. Stearns showed that given a Turing machine Mα that halts on input x within N steps, then there exists a multi-tape universal Turing machine that halts on inputs α, x (given on different tapes) in CN log N, where C is a machine-specific constant that does not depend on the length of the input x, but does depend on M's alphabet size, number of tapes, and number of states - or does a UTM with C = 1 not exist? Thank you